# Sending a big buffer through uart in Qt5

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qstring

I'm a beginner in Qt. Now I want to use Qt5 to send a 9-byte command through uart.
Here is my command:

```
FFFFFF5550464DAA0E
```

I want to transfer my command to a Qstring object. When I write my code like this, it tells me the const is too big.

```
QString str=0xFFFFFF5550464DAA0E;
```

So I choose an array like this, but it still doesn't work.

```
char cmd[9]={0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0x55,0x50,0x46,0x4D,0xAA,0x0E};
for(int i=0;i<9;i++)
{
    QString str=cmd[i];
    QByteArray outData=str.toLatin1();
    int size=outData.size();
    outData=myHelper::HexStrToByteArray(str);
    size=outData.size();
    myCom->write(outData);
}
```

I also try this which failes again

```
char cmd[9]={0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0x55,0x50,0x46,0x4D,0xAA,0x0E};
QString str=cmd;
QByteArray outData=str.toLatin1();
int size=outData.size();
outData=myHelper::HexStrToByteArray(str);
size=outData.size();
myCom->write(outData);
```

So could anyone tell me how to do this ?

Comment: Do you know the difference between `0xFF` and `"0xFF"`?

Comment: thank you @paxdiablo with your help now it works.I'm really appreciate it

Comment: thank you for ur effort @Adriano Repetti and I think your answer can help the beginner a lot

Comment: @ctxrr you welcome, I hope it can't help. Small tip: in future SO questions try to post more about _context_ (for example exact data you expect to send over the wirte), it may reduce answers to few lines of code (without need to _guess_) ;)

Comment: @Adriano Repetti Ok I will.Thank you for your recommendation.I'm not only a beginner of Qt but also a newcomer to stack overflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line of code:

```
QString str=0xFFFFFF5550464DAA0E;
```

`0xFFFFFF5550464DAA0E` is not a string. You're trying to assign a very big constant (9 bytes) **number to a string**. Note that `0xFF` is not a string but a character with ASCII code `0xFF`. With your second attempt you're on the right way:

```
char cmd[9]={0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0x55,0x50,0x46,0x4D,0xAA,0x0E};
```

Now you have two options; it depends on what you have to send, 9 bytes or a longer string with that commands represented as a *hex string* and encoded as ASCII. First case is easier, drop all your code:

```
QByteArray outData = QByteArray(cmd, sizeof(cmd));
myCom->write(outData);
```

With this code you won't send a string to your device but 9 bytes (`0xFF`...`0x0E`). If you have to send a string then you can do what paxdiablo suggested:

```
QByteArray outData = QByteArray("\xFF\xFF\xFF\x55\x50\x46\x4D\xAA\x0E", 9);
myCom->write(outData);
```

Or:

```
QByteArray outData = QString("0xFF0xFF0xFF0x550x500x460x4D0xAA0x0E")
    .toLatin1();
myCom->write(outData);
```

Or in alternative you can do this:

```
char cmd[9]={0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0x55,0x50,0x46,0x4D,0xAA,0x0E};
QByteArray outData = QByteArray(cmd, sizeof(cmd)).toHex();
myCom->write(outData);
```

Which one is right for you? Well you should clarify your context...

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to mess about with strings and conversions. You can just make the `QByteArray` *directly* from the data itself, with a simple one-liner:

```
QbyteArray data("\xFF\xFF\xFF\x55\x50\x46\x4D\xAA\x0E", 9);
```

Following that, the statement:

```
myCom->write(data);
```

will then output the nine bytes as specified in the string.

Comment: I don't think this is the problem, since it is (almost) the same as the OP already did. The problem seems to be in the conversion to a QString.

Comment: What I' saying is that there's no _need_ to convert it to a string, you can just create the byte array directly.

Comment: Ah, okay... didn't get that